# How to mass update metadata on thousands of files on Amazon S3 files?

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm hosting thousands of images on s3 and now realize that I need to set a "expire" value in the metadata.

DragonDisk doesn't let me update properties for multiple files.
Looks like in the S3 console I would have to scroll to the end of a list in order to do a mass update. Not practical with 100,000 images in one directly.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Which programming languages/OS are you using?

Comment: Mac, could use php if necessary

Comment: Write a simple php script using the amazon s3 php sdk?

Comment: I was hoping for a tool I can use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DragonDisk v1.0 do that : Right click on the folder -> Properties -> Child Objects.